# how to wrap a text around a image?

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image of which i want some text will be wrap around. I placed the image a bit higher by giving a negative top value and making its position relative. But it shows some white space under the image. I want to remove the white space with texts. How can I do that?

Here is the html code

```css
.what_text_container>p {}

.what_text_container>p>span {
  font-style: italic
}

.what_text_container>img {
  border-radius: 15px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="what_text_container">
  <img src="assets/images/carolina.png" width="324" height="215" alt="" />
  <p>
    <span>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful.</span>
    <br> "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
    of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves
    or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical
    exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"<br>
    <br> "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
    of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves
    or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example,<br>
    <br> "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
    of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves
    or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical
    exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"

  </p>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: @emmanuel op wants the image higher!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the top attribute.

keep your css like this.

```
.what_text_container > p {

}

.what_text_container > p > span {
    font-style:italic
}

.what_text_container > img {
  border-radius: 15px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
```

or remove the position:

```
.what_text_container > p {

}

.what_text_container > p > span {
    font-style:italic
}



.what_text_container > img {
  border-radius: 15px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
.what_text_container > img {
  border-radius: 15px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -150px;
}
```